# Typescript combined types

Tags: typescript

I have the following type declaration

```
export declare type Education = {
    id: string;
    name: string;     
} & ({
    completed: false;
    completionDate?: {year: number, month: number};
} | {
    completed: true;
    completionDate?: {
        year: number;
    };
})
```

Now I'm trying to convert the following object

```
const a = {
   id: 'id1',
   name: 'testName'
   completed: true
}
```

Into the above type, but cannot figure out how to handle the situation where completed is true and completed is false.

for example if I have the following method

```
const convert = (): Education =>{
 return {
   id: a.id,
   name: a.name,
   // Stuck here
 }
}
```

Comment: [Like this?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiATArgYwIYwCWEAdnALxwDeAUHHIRgFxwDOMUhJA5gNx1wSeALbAW7Tj34BfOADI4ACgEAfagPr0cEYWAA2wGMGZwAZnj2tg-TZu26DRUgBECwAPwsqcRMDxQWEixhACNgKF44YVIYAAtA4LCoOGkbTWlVdVstHX1DYxYOLGsNO1zHYhJXI08s7PpffwTQ8LTbVNLpAEp+Gm0Sdjg8FkxcAkqKOsYWACJGAEYZgBoBIVFZo3YAORFgZYF7PKMTIuAaDr7SQf6AN3D4SkUukex8JzJyAD46qEMsKDItFs0yGADpGCtbGsxGDoZCyg58iY8KDDo5jAIOh0gA) or if not, what exactly is your issue?

Comment: not exactly, so if completed 'true' I need to assign the year only, if not I need to assign bot the year and month.  Plus I also have an issue where I get cannot convert boolean to true

Comment: So, like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiATArgYwIYwCWEAdnALxwDeAUHHIRgFxwDOMUhJA5gNx1wSeALbAW7Tj34BfOADI4ACgEAfagPr0cEYWAA2wGMGZwAZnj2tg-TZu26DRUgBECwAPwsqcRMDxQWEixhACNgKF44YVIYAAtA4LCoOGkbTWlVdVstHX1DYxYOLGsNO1zHYhJXI08s7PpffwTQ8LTbVNLpAEp+Gm0Sdjg8FkxcAkqKOsYWACJGAEYZgBoBIVFZo3YAORFgZYF7PKMTIuAaDr7SQf6AN3D4SkUukex8JzJyAD46qEMsKDIAHkQgArYA4GAAOjwrFYhG4JGUtm80yGkMYS0EuxYeEha1Q0hWtlxh0cxlK9Hc1DgpPyJygxSGrBpVxgmNp72qYmpjQCcAATAAGIUpFIUuBeFkOOkscyWVAwlkDNlSo6VLmS3ksIVCzHREhxFgAFlFGXoPXO-CAA)?

Comment: If not, please edit the code here to constitute a [mcve] as described in the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  It's easier to get help if you can demonstrate the issue in question instead of just talking about it.  Good luck!

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCiATArgYwIYwCWEAdnALxwDeAUHHIRgFxwDOMUhJA5gNx1wSeALbAW7Tj34BfOADI4ACgEAfagPr0cEYWAA2wGMGZwAZnj2tg-TZu26DRUgBECwAPwsqcRMDxQWEixhACNgKF44YVIYAAtA4LCoOGkbTWlVdVstHX1DYxYOLGsNO1zHYhJXI08s7PpffwTQ8LTbVNLpAEp+Gm0Sdjg8FkxcAkqKOsYWACJGAEYZgBoBIVFZo3YAORFgZYF7PKMTIuAaDr7SQf6AN3D4SkUukex8JzJyAD46qEMsKDIAHkQgArYA4GAAOjwrFYhG4JGUtm80yGkMYS0EuxYeEha1Q0hWtlxh0cxlK9Hc1DgpPyJygxSGrBpVxgmNp72qYmpjQCcAATAAGIUpFIUuBeFkOOkscyWVAwlkDNlSo6VLmS3ksIVCzHREhxFgAFlFGXoPXO-CAA just what I was looking for.  Thanks